# Retrieve a list of all users in Trac

Tags: trac, user-accounts

Is there a way to get all users of the current Trac environment via Python? Similar to `model.Priority.select(self.env)` which returns a list of all priorities. Maybe there is a method of the Trac Account Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Environment.get_known_users()](http://www.edgewall.org/docs/branches-1.0-stable/html/api/trac_env.html#trac.env.Environment.get_known_users) will give you a list of all known users that have logged in. Inside a class inheriting from `Component` you can use `self.env.get_known_users()`.